# How can I change the homepage of all my browsers with a single click?

Tags: browser, homepage

I want to change all of my browsers' home pages with a single click. Are there any programs capable of doing this for me?

Comment: Probably not - the browsers are all separate programs with separate settings, options and registry keys. Some also have protection to stop hopepage 'hijacks' from happening

Comment: If you're by any chance talking about sharing settings between several Firefox browsers on different machines, you can accomplish this by using its built-in **Sync** feature. This requires you to click up to several times, and some typing is needed.

Comment: How many browsers do you have that you can't just manually change it? it takes all of 5 seconds to change per browser and it's not like you have to do it over and over again. Unless you like to change your homepage on a daily basis for fun. hehe

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention whether it was Windows/Linux. Not difficult to write scripts to do this actually. The following will deal with Iceweasal/Firefox.

cat prefs.js | egrep -v "\bbrowser.startup.homepage\b" > new.js
cat prefs.js | egrep "\bbrowser.startup.homepage\b" | sed s/"about:blank"/"newpage"/ >> new.js
cp pref.js pref.js.old
cp new.js pref.js

Same thing for Opera on the following file.

operaprefs.ini

Obviously, IE is a registry fix.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/registry-hack-to-set-internet-explorer-start-page/

Spend some time on modifying these scripts and you'll be able to set things automatically across most of the popular browsers.